# Why doesn't Interface assignment consider method parameter types

Tags: typescript

**Update:** Sorry.  I jumped the gun when posting my original code sample.  I've updated the code and tested in a separate project.  It seems my issue arises when the derived interface includes a method with the same name and first parameter type, but then has ADDTIONAL parameters (that the base interface does not have).  Repro repo here (in case I copy/pasted any code incorrectly): https://github.com/lukewis/typescript_interface_assignment

It seems that when typescript is considering whether or not an object implements an interface, it doesn't consider parameter types when comparing functions.  I'm guessing this was a deliberate design choice, but it doesn't make any sense to me.  Consider the following:

```
interface IBase {
    id: string;
}

interface IFoo extends IBase {
    method1(param1: string): void;
}

interface IBar extends IBase {
    method1(param1: string, param2: boolean): void;
}

class Foo implements IFoo {
    public readonly id = "foo";

    public method1(param1: string): void {
    }
}

// The following line compiles with NO ERROR....but why??
const bar: IBar = new Foo();
```

I'm guessing maybe this has something to do with variadic functions in javascript?  But it's baffling to me that this behavior compiles.  Can anyone offer an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: This does not compile for me [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IFoo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20method1(param1%3A%20string)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IBar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20method1(param1%3A%20boolean)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20implements%20IFoo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20method1(param1%3A%20string)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20The%20following%20line%20compiles%20with%20NO%20ERROR%0D%0Aconst%20bar%3A%20IBar%20%3D%20new%20Foo()%3B).

Comment: Also, what's your `tsc` version?

Comment: It doesn't compile because the parameters of method1 differ, one is of type boolean and the other of type string. "Error: Types of parameters 'param1' and 'param1' are incompatible. Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'"

Comment: @user2347763 Yes, but it apparently compiles for him. That's the question.

Comment: Thanks so much for the replies everyone!  When I copy that code into a new project, I do indeed see the compiler error, so it must be something with my current project configuration.  Let me dig a little deeper and then I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code contains an error and always has. You've done something wrong on your end if you're not seeing the error.

[image]

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I should have done more testing before I posted my code sample.  I've updated my sample code with a more accurate representation of the issue I'm seeing.  So sorry for wasting your time with my first post!  I'm hoping you might still be willing to comment on the updated version.

Comment: It's in the TypeScript FAQ: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters

Comment: Thanks for the link Ryan!  The FAQ speaks of an example of assigning functions to callback parameters.  I can certainly appreciate that it's useful to allow assigning a callback function with fewer parameters than the method actually takes.  However, it still feels weird in this scenario when we're talking about interface "implementation" rather than just function "assignability".  The FAQ also states that "this sort of enforcement wouldn't ever directly fix a bug".  I'm not sure I agree with that statement in this particular context.